# Unexpected Result with Case When statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

This Case When in my query is returning unexpected results. Basically if the funding (Sub Query Case When) is under 3000 the value should be 3000. It is returning 0, i know this seems like a silly question but im really stuck on this one.

Ive tried just executing the query on its own and it still returns 0. I have also tried this without the literals.

```
SELECT 
Tax + StudentLoans AS 'Net Income Tax',
GrossNI,
CASE WHEN ed.EA_Indicator_CY = '0' THEN '0' ELSE 
(SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(Funding) > '3000' THEN '0' ELSE '3000' END FROM 
PayrollRuns) END AS 'Employment Allowance',
SMP AS 'SMP Recovered',
NICompOnSMP AS 'SMP Comp',
SPPA + SPPB AS 'SPP Recovered',
SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation AS 'SPP COMP',
SAP AS 'SAP Recovered',
SAPCompensation,
SHPP_A + SHPP_B AS 'Shpp Recovered',
SHPP_A_Compensation + SHPP_B_Compensation AS 'ShPP Comp',
Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
FROM PayrollRuns pr
CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
WHERE RunID = '1058'
GROUP BY Tax, StudentLoans, GrossNI, SMP, NICompOnSMP, ed.EA_Indicator_CY, 
SPPACompensation, SPPBCompensation, SAPCompensation, SHPP_A_Compensation, 
SHPP_B_Compensation, SPPA, SPPB, SAP, Apprenticeship_Levy_Due, SHPP_A, 
SHPP_B
```

My Employment Allowance column for this example should be coming back as 3000 but it is coming as 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of subquery SUM(Funding)  ?

Comment: @Chanukya SUM(Funding) = 0

Comment: I think it should be a number rather than a string..

Comment: I think it's because EA_Indicator_CY is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use number and not string

```
SELECT 
    Tax + StudentLoans AS 'Net Income Tax',
    GrossNI,
    CASE WHEN ed.EA_Indicator_CY = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 
    ( CASE WHEN  (SELECT  SUM(Funding) FROM PayrollRuns > 3000 ) THEN 0 ELSE 3000 END )
        END AS 'Employment Allowance',
    SMP AS 'SMP Recovered',
    NICompOnSMP AS 'SMP Comp',
    SPPA + SPPB AS 'SPP Recovered',
    SPPACompensation + SPPBCompensation AS 'SPP COMP',
    SAP AS 'SAP Recovered',
    SAPCompensation,
    SHPP_A + SHPP_B AS 'Shpp Recovered',
    SHPP_A_Compensation + SHPP_B_Compensation AS 'ShPP Comp',
    Apprenticeship_Levy_Due AS 'App Levy'
    FROM PayrollRuns pr
    CROSS JOIN [Employer Details] ed
    WHERE RunID = '1058'
    GROUP BY Tax, StudentLoans, GrossNI, SMP, NICompOnSMP, ed.EA_Indicator_CY, 
    SPPACompensation, SPPBCompensation, SAPCompensation, SHPP_A_Compensation, 
    SHPP_B_Compensation, SPPA, SPPB, SAP, Apprenticeship_Levy_Due, SHPP_A, 
    SHPP_B
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Although i should have stated in my question that i have tried that and output is still the same. Thanks though

Comment: Yes :(... Even when i try and execute the Case When by itself it still returns 0. It definitely shouldn't be 0

Comment: Check for your real value of EA_Indicator_CY   and for sum(funding)

Comment: EA_Indicator_CY = 1... SUM(Funding) = 0

Comment: answer  updated ..  changing when (select sum...) instead of select case .. in the inner case

Comment: Super Duper. Had to make one slight change but this was a massive help. Thank you so much. Marked as accepted answer :)